# Fridge/freezer door keep closed

Tags: kitchens

Whenever I close the fridge door,the freezer door below pops open. Sometimes it closes by itself but equally it often stays open allowing the freezer to defrost.
I wondered if I could use magnets somehow to keep the freezer door closed.Any ideas?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. This probably isn't a good place for you to get design suggestions for your need; the answers would be too broad. You should take the tour to see how better to participate here.

Answer (score 1):

The gasket on the freezer door actually has magnets in it.
Sounds like your gasket isn't making good contact with the door -- either replace the gasket or clean it, or make sure that the hinges are perfectly aligned.

Answer (score 1):

I have the exact same issue in my apartment. (my gf always does this, and I'm the only one noticing it!). I always thought this was the result of bad levelling. Have you tried tilting the fridge back a bit?

Comment: To clarify, many refrigerators have adjustable front feet or wheel perches. There's probably a nut that can be accessed from behind the grille.

Answer (score 0):

It would be helpful to know what kind of refrigerator/freezer you are speaking about.  If it is a two chamber commercial unit, so called walk-in the cause could be air pressure from closing the door forcefully passing through any opening between the two areas and pushing the other door open.  Also requires a magnetic type gasket vs a rubber gasket with a positive close latch which would not open if latched properly.  If it is a residential unit then possibly the fridge is not level and closing the door hard is enough to break the magnetic seal.  There are leveling legs under the front corners which are adjustable.